# django apache deployment serve django templates as static html

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment

my django apache deployment serve django templates as static html

I am getting below tags on my webpage

```
{% if cmd %} {{ cmd }} {% endif %} {% if command %} {{ command}}
Running python script baby....wait...

{% endif %} {% if documents %}
{% for document in documents %} {% endfor %}
{% else %}
No documents.

{% endif %} {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

Is there something wrong with my deployment configuration

I am using Apache2 on my locale ubuntu box for deployment.

Comment: How your template directory looks in settings.py file ?

Comment: TEMPLETE_DIRS = ( 
'/var/www/TEServices/templates',
)

Comment: How are we expected to diagnose your Apache setup when you haven't provided any details of your Apache configuration, the URL you're using, your Django urls.py and views code, or anything else relevant?

Answer (score 1):

my deployment's settings:
Project structre:

```
sites/
└── motivate-me.local
    ├── project
    │   ├── api
    │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── v1
    │   │       └── __pycache__
    │   └── project
    │       └── __pycache__
    └── static
        ├── admin
        │   ├── css
        │   ├── img
        │   │   └── gis
        │   └── js
        │       └── admin
        └── rest_framework
            ├── css
            ├── img
            └── js
```

django.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/mikhail/sites/motivate-me.local/')
sys.path.append('/home/mikhail/sites/motivate-me.local/project/')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

My hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.2   www
127.0.0.3   loss-weight.local
127.0.0.4   test.local
127.0.0.5   motivate-me.local
127.0.1.1   ube-work

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@motivate-me.local
ServerName motivate-me.local
ServerAlias motivate-me.local

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mikhail/sites/motivate-me.local/project.wsgi
WSGIPassAuthorization on

DocumentRoot /home/mikhail/sites/motivate-me.local
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/mikhail/sites/motivate-me.local/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/mikhail/sites/motivate-me.local/static/
<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working with below details

Create a .wsgi file(like mysite.wsgi) for you project with below information at any location preferably inside project

```
import os
import sys
path = '/home/synerzip/Documents/pavanWork/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Create a .conf file inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias /  /path/to/.wsgi                    # file which is created in above step
ServerName mysite.com                                       # Name of your site
Alias /static/  /path/to/your/project /static/files
<Directory /path/to/your/project />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache server